# Form horizontal bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

im using a bootstrap horitonzal form, this works 
But I have 3 forms for each row but I want to have a single form to get the same effect as a horizontal form with several rows.  But I have 3 forms for each row but I want to have a single form to get the same effect as a horizontal form with several rows.

My idea is to make validations and for that I need to include all the inputs in a single form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="frm1" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="txtNombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNombre" ng-model="model.nombre" placeholder="Rut">
        </div>


        <label for="txtRut" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Rut</label>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRut" placeholder="Rut">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <input type="password" id="txtDv" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Dv">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="txtMail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtMail" placeholder="e-mail">
        </div>


        <label for="txtAlias" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Alias</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAlias" placeholder="Alias">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="selEmpresa" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Empresa</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="selEmpresa">
                <option>Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>


        <label for="chkActive" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Activo</label>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkActive">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achievalbe using row and cols as below

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="frm1" role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="txtNombre" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNombre" ng-model="model.nombre" placeholder="Rut">
            </div>


            <label for="txtRut" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Rut</label>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRut" placeholder="Rut">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="password" id="txtDv" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Dv">
            </div>
        </div>

</div></div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="txtMail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtMail" placeholder="e-mail">
            </div>


            <label for="txtAlias" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Alias</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAlias" placeholder="Alias">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="selEmpresa" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Empresa</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select class="form-control" id="selEmpresa">
                    <option>Audi</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <label for="chkActive" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Activo</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkActive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```